# The annoying XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent text in Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I'm trying to load into website the date and events from Google Calendar using json. But in the output appears the annoying text "object XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent" if I use Chrome, but it is not displayed in Firefox. The website is intended to be displayed in mobiles using android. Here I show what the console shows:

[image]

Please, can you give me any suggestion to remove this text from the output?

**Edited**
By request of jarrodeck, here is the javascript

```
var event = 'Next Events<br><br>';
var gclaData ='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json&orderby=starttime&max-results=5&singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true';

$.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(j, entry){
    event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
    event += '<div class="eventTime">'+ entry.gd$when[0].startTime+"</div>";
    event += '<div class="eventName">'+ entry.title.$t + "</div>";
    event += '</div>';
    event +='<hr>';
});
$('#output').html(event);
});
```

Comment: Can you show JavaScript code that generates this issue? For sure you're appending a string representation of XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent instead of some value from the response. Probable somewhere in 'load' event handler for XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: You should add comment so I'll get notification about change :) Well, it's not in this part of the code. Are you sure that there's no other place where `event` variable is concatenated with some object? Alternatively you can move `var event = '...'` inside $.getJSON function.

Comment: sorry man. But what about this issue doesn't happen in Firefox? the same code in Firefox runs perfectly!

Comment: damn, you were right, I put the event='next events' after first brackets and now everything is ok.

Comment: So there must be somewhere in your code a place where you append some object to this string.